# Renaming sysfs attributes for identical usb devices

Tags: linux, usb, udev, alsa

I'm trying to rename the "product name" of two usb devices that are identical, so I can distinguish them when using them.

The devices in question are USB MIDI Interfaces (https://tie-products.com/en/produkt/midi-1i1o/)

Tried **a lot** of stuff, but now I'm stuck and cannot get anywhere. Is this even possible?

[image]

```bash
Aug 21 22:57:54 studio kernel: [    2.543513] usb 11-2.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=fc02, idProduct=0101, bcdDevice= 2.50
Aug 21 22:57:54 studio kernel: [    2.543520] usb 11-2.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Aug 21 22:57:54 studio kernel: [    2.543524] usb 11-2.1.2: Product: USB MIDI Interface
..
Aug 21 22:57:54 studio kernel: [    3.379800] usb 11-2.1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=fc02, idProduct=0101, bcdDevice= 2.50
Aug 21 22:57:54 studio kernel: [    3.379807] usb 11-2.1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Aug 21 22:57:54 studio kernel: [    3.379811] usb 11-2.1.3: Product: USB MIDI Interface
```

```bash
> udevadm info -a -p /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0/usb11/11-2/11-2.1/11-2.1.2

#  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0/usb11/11-2/11-2.1/11-2.1.2':
#    KERNEL=="11-2.1.2"
#    SUBSYSTEM=="usb"
#    DRIVER=="usb"
#    ..
#    ATTR{product}=="USB MIDI Interface"
#    ..
```

These are my simple rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-custom-usb-midi.rules`:

```bash
DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0/usb11/11-2/11-2.1/11-2.1.2", ATTR{product}="USB MIDI Interface A"
DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0/usb11/11-2/11-2.1/11-2.1.3", ATTR{product}="USB MIDI Interface B"
```

```bash
> udevadm test /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0/usb11/11-2/11-2.1/11-2.1.2
#  ..
#  11-2.1.2: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-custom-usb-midi.rules:1 Failed to write ATTR{/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0/usb11/11-2/11-2.1/11-2.1.2/product}, ignoring: Permission denied
#  ..
```

**UPDATE 1**

The article linked by MC68020 below explains how one can edit some of this stuff (*Alf_test*). This however was not enough for me to change the **name** (*USB MIDI Interface*) of the MIDI devices, which is my goal here.

[image: Debug image]

```bash
> ls -l /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0/usb11/11-2/11-2.2/11-2.2.4/11-2.2.4:1.0/sound/card7/id
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 31 08:57 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0/usb11/11-2/11-2.2/11-2.2.4/11-2.2.4:1.0/sound/card7/id

> cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0/usb11/11-2/11-2.2/11-2.2.4/11-2.2.4:1.0/sound/card7/id
Alf_test

> ls -l /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0/usb11/11-2/11-2.2/11-2.2.4/product
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 31 08:38 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0/usb11/11-2/11-2.2/11-2.2.4/product

> cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0/usb11/11-2/11-2.2/11-2.2.4/product
USB MIDI Interface
```

**UPDATE 2**

I noticed that `aconnect -l` shows a prepended string `MIDI 1` which is actually what is shown in Bitwig.

Is it possible to change that string then?

```bash
> aconnect -l
..
client 36: 'Fastlane' [type=kernel,card=5]
    0 'Fastlane MIDI A '
    1 'Fastlane MIDI B '
client 40: 'Faderfox PC4' [type=kernel,card=6]
    0 'Faderfox PC4 MIDI 1'
client 44: 'USB MIDI Interface' [type=kernel,card=7]
    0 'USB MIDI Interface MIDI 1'
client 48: 'USB MIDI Interface' [type=kernel,card=8]
    0 'USB MIDI Interface MIDI 1'
client 52: 'Intech Studio: Grid' [type=kernel,card=9]
    0 'Intech Studio: Grid MIDI 1'
..
```

[image: Debug]

**UPDATE 3 - Conclusion**

My conclusion so far is that this just isn't possible, which is kind of sucky, but can't have it all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand reading your udev rules, you ar trying to change the value of the *product* key.

This is just not possible since, regarding an usb device, this info comes directly from the [device-descriptor](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#DeviceDescriptors) and is therefore not modifiable.
Hence the `ignoring: Permission denied` you obtain as a result.

What you want to change is indeed the NAME key. Unfortunately, udev does not provide that possibility according to `man udev` :

> The name of a device node cannot be changed by udev, only additional
> symlinks can be created.

You'll take note of the advice given : Create a symlink! It might just fit your need, simply change the action to undertake with :

`SYMLINK+="USB_MIDI_Interface_A"` for the first rule and
`SYMLINK+="USB_MIDI_Interface_B"` for the second.

---

**EDIT since only alsa devices are concerned.**

Alsa describes in details a [method for identifying two identical devices using udev.](https://alsa.opensrc.org/Udev#Writing_udev_rules)

This method is based on changing the card id that you can read in `/proc/asound/cardX/id`

In short, in order to automatize the change thanks to udev, you'd just need to write the following rules :

```
SUBSYSTEM!="sound", GOTO="my_usb_audio_end"
ACTION!="add", GOTO="my_usb_audio_end"

DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-6/2-6.2/2-6.2:1.0/sound/card?", ATTR{id}="UA1A_A"
DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-6/2-6.3/2-6.3:1.0/sound/card?", ATTR{id}="UA1A_B"

LABEL="my_usb_audio_end"
```

Of course, you'll want to adapt to your devpaths and care I cannot tell if there is a max nb of characters allowed for the string label, nor if spaces are allowed.

You'll also want to check using `amidi -l` or `cat /proc/asound/cards`.
I just checked pluging my Neutron synth… it just works. (however… I just like that name ;-P )
Also checked that rosegarden uses this identifier in the studio > manage midi devices dialog box.

Comment: Thank you. Adding these symlinks won't help me much as most programs will just display the product name. I added an image to my question to illustrate my point better. Is there nothing to do about this?

Comment: @Fractalf : I'm stupid ! I had not read that only midi devices were concerned. In which case, using alsa midi I presume with amidi / aconnect ( or graphical equivalents) ? In which case… there is a way ! I updated my answer !

Comment: You seem far from stupid to me :) I've had some busy days, but will look into this new info when time allows! Thank you for your effort!

Comment: I had some time to look at this, and though I managed to change the stuff you are talking about, it didn't help me much, as the name of the MIDI interfaces still remain the same. Will update my answer to illustrate

Comment: @Fractalf : What is the application you are running showing the image you posted in first part ? some graphical equivalent to aconnect I presume. If, under whatever terminal you fire *aconnect -l* (minus L) can you read the ids as reprogrammed ?

Comment: My screenshot is from Drumstick MIDI Monitor (https://kmidimon.sourceforge.io/), but my DAW is Bitwig. I ran `aconnect -l` which showed the same name as the others (*USB MIDI Interface*), and not the one I managed to change (which was just the `id`)

Comment: I did some more debug today (with `aconnect -l`) and noticed that in Bitwig the prepended string "MIDI 1" is actually shown. Any idea if I can actually change this? (see my updated answer for screenshots etc)

Comment: @Fractalf :  OK then, must be running a higher version of the alsa-libs than the one I am playing with. The penultimate idea I had was to fiddle some kernel usb quirck. I just failed understanding how it is possible to match repeated occurrences of identical product/vendor ids. The only door left opened being to fiddle in alsa-libs/src/seq* . My next week is off… I'll see what I can do.