# How to select card in amixer by name

Tags: linux, drivers, audio, alsa, usb-device

I have a razer headset which has a usb sound card that can be used with it (BlacShark V2).
From some point, when I boot up the system (The headset is usually connected to my system and I don't unplug it), the speaker gain of the headset was randomly set to lower numbers. I found out that I can change them from `alsamixer`, and then I tried to find a way to set them with a script so that I can run that every time I boot up the system. Then I found out about 'amixer', and the final command looks like this:
`amixer -c 1 cset numid=9,iface=MIXER,name='Speaker Playback Volume' 64`
This command sets the gain to maximum, and when I wrote it and saved it in a bash script, my headset was on card number 1.
The problem is that sometimes my razer headset is recognized as card 2, and then running this command doesn't do what it meant to do.

Is there some way that I can identify which card I want to set controls for by the card name? If no, can I at least give the headset card a fixed number so that I can reliably run the command? Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve your problem (not necessarily answering your question as worded in the title). One of these, assuming you want your amixer command to be efficient and your alsa drivers are built as modules (not in-kernel) consists in forcing the cards to load in some precise order

From :

```
acoswt@Tux ~ $ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Loopback       ]: Loopback - Loopback
                      Loopback 1
 1 [VirMIDI        ]: VirMIDI - VirMIDI
                      Virtual MIDI Card 1
 2 [M2496          ]: ICE1712 - M Audio Audiophile 24/96
                      M Audio Audiophile 24/96 at 0xec00, irq 17
 3 [Exchange       ]: USB-Audio - Hercules Dualpix Exchange
                      Guillemot Corporation Hercules Dualpix Exchange at usb-0000:00:1d.7-3, high spe
```

I can realize that my M Audio Audiophile sound card sits at index 2 driven by the snd-ice1712 alsa driver and that the audio subsystem of my usb webcam sits at index 3 driven by the snd-usb-audio driver.

Would I prefer to permanently (across reboots) force them to sit at index 0 and 1 respectively, that I would just need to add the following to `/etc/modprobe.d/sound` or (whatever other name with a .conf extension):

```
options snd-ice1712 index=0
options snd-usb-audio index=1
```

BTW : Take care, some configuration file might already exist depending on your distribution (namely alsa.conf, alsa-base.conf…) and potentially force parameters conflicting with the instructions as given above.
In which case, do prefer reediting these existing files accordingly, taking care of other lines that could eventually take precedence / override / conflict with your new settings.

Comment: On modern systems, there is often the little problem that the audio cards you want to persistently arrange are both using the same module. This often crops up with `snd-hda-intel` and `snd-usb-audio`. At least the `snd-usb-audio` module has the `vid=` and `pid=` options, which can be used to specify the audio devices by vendor/product IDs, respectively. But getting two HD-Audio cards into a specific order (other than the default order by increasing PCI bus IDs) seems to be tricky.

Comment: @telcoM : You are correct. In these particular cases, one would need to resort to udev for differentiating as described in the EDIT part of my answer to this question : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714395/renaming-sysfs-attributes-for-identical-usb-devices/714894#714894

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was away for a little and just got the chance to access my system. I didn't have `/etc/modprobe.d/sound`, and before creating one, I saw `alsa-base.conf` there and it had this line: `options snd-usb-audio index=-2`. Apparently this prevents "abnormal" drivers grabbing 0 index (which btw I wanted to ask if it is a special index which seems it is). My question is that should I edit this line? Or I can just add the `sound` file and it would overwrite the line mentioned here?

Comment: @III_phr : You can indeed prefer editing alsa-base.conf. As a matter of fact whatever .conf would fit. Alas suggests alas.conf… anyway. So yes ! Do change the line you mentioned to show index=1 instead of index=-2. (Of course take care that other lines do not conflict with this choice)

Comment: @III_phr : index 0 would (unless special fiddlings as part of some .asoundrc file) specify the default device used by alsa. Since USB devices might not be always connected it might be considered pertinent to prevent these devices to stand for default. You can look to my list of cards displayed in my answer. On my system, index 0 is associated to the loopback driver. This is typically sort of "abnormal" driver since it is not linked to a "real" sound device. In my case, this is made on purpose but for most standard cases it could be considered absurd to let this "abnormal" device the default.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain these :D. I did edit the `alsa-base.conf` and will test it later this day to find out if I did it right or not. I think my problem is solved so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: A note for future visitors. If you ended up editing `alsa-base.conf` file, make sure to respect the order of `option`s there. If there are other `option some-card index=something` lines before the one you add, they will have higher priority and even if the index is `-2`, it means that some index will be assigned to that particular card and it might be the one you want to assign for yourself. At least I derived this from what I saw, I may be wrong xd.

Comment: Thx @III_phr for noticing. I added an extra warning at the end of my answer.