# Make USB audio device default

Tags: usb, audio, alsa, defaults

1. Running Debian :

   ```
   # uname --kernel-name --kernel-release --machine
   Linux 6.5.11-7-pve x86_64
   # cat /proc/asound/cards
   0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                       HDA Intel PCH at 0xfb410000 irq 98
   2 [USB            ]: USB-Audio - Scarlett Solo USB
                       Focusrite Scarlett Solo USB at usb-0000:00:14.0-7, high speed
   ```
2. Each time I boot, the order of the sound card changes, i.e. USB is randomly 0 or 2
3. How do I make sure USB is the default every time?

### UPDATE1

```
root@pve:/scripts# cat /etc/modprobe.d/sound/alsa.conf
# makes usb audio always index 0, needs reboot
options snd-usb-audio index=0
options snd-hda-intel index=1
root@pve:/scripts# cat /etc/asound.conf
defaults.pcm.card 2
defaults.ctl.card 2
root@pve:/scripts#
```

This is what I currently have, but USB can still end up as 2 and I had to use `/etc/asound.conf` to make it default without performing another reboot and hope it ends up as 0

### UPDATE2

```
# cat /etc/modprobe.d/*.conf
# makes usb audio always index 0, needs reboot
#options snd-usb-audio index=0
#options snd-hda-intel index=1
# This file contains a list of modules which are not supported by Proxmox VE

# nvidiafb see bugreport https://bugzilla.proxmox.com/show_bug.cgi?id=701
blacklist nvidiafb
options zfs zfs_arc_max=13488881664
```

Comment: Does the answer I provided as part of this question ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/765289/how-to-select-card-in-amixer-by-name/765342#765342 ) solve your problem ?

Comment: that would be this in my case, correct?
```
options snd-usb-audio index=0
options snd-hda-intel index=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the dramatic reaction to my use of Proxmox,

I found the answer in a Linux related forum,
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=224241

It involves having a `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa.conf` with `options snd slots=snd-usb-audio,snd-hda-intel`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT : From what appears in comment #7, OP is running a proxmox environment. Therefore, the following answer is not likely to provide a working solution.**

---

Adapting [my answer to another question worded differently.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/765289/how-to-select-card-in-amixer-by-name/765342#765342)

Unless otherwise specified as part of miscellaneous alsa configuration files (namely `/etc/asound.conf`, `$HOME/.asoundrc`), alsa default device is identified as `card 0`. which is generally the first sound device enumerated as such by the kernel.
Depending on the number of devices available, their type (pci, usb), the order in which devices will get discovered and consequently assigned to some id is mostly unpredictable.

If the alsa drivers are built as modules (not in-kernel built), the card id association will be deferred at init time and the init system can be instructed to enforce a dedicated order :

All you need is edit some `.conf` file in the `/etc/modprobe.d/` directory. (edit an already existing one since some distributions ships with a default `alsa-base.conf` or create some new, alsa recommends `alsa.conf`) and insert / modify two lines as follows :

```
options snd-usb-audio index=0
options snd-hda-intel index=1
```

Of course you will want to ensure that no other `option` instruction conflicts with / takes precedence over these settings, which is likely in many distributions commonly preferring on-board hardware to external devices that might not always be connected when assigning defaults.

Comment: Sorry, but this did not work, after one of the reboot, I ended up with USB as 2 again. I also have /etc/asound.conf as a workaround to make USB usable when it was 2. See my OP.

Comment: @bilogic : MYBAD ! I made a typo : The .conf file (with the option statements) must be immediately in the **/etc/modprobe.d** directory (and not /etc/modprobe.d/sound as I had erroneously written). I stand corrected.

Comment: I tried it out again, but my USB audio goes missing. Could it be that I need to set my indexes as 0 and 2 instead?

Comment: @bilogic : did you ensure that there are no conflicting statements set as part of other *.conf file of the /etc/modprobe.d directory ?

Comment: I did, please see my OP. Perhaps let me put it this way, the lines you suggested did have an effect, it caused the USB audio not to load. Or should I try to use index 1 and 2?

Comment: @bilogic : Is your usb audio device connected at boot time ? Are you running a standard debian ? (just asking because I'm left surprised that the distro does not come with defaults .conf regarding alsa.

Comment: Yes, all my devices are constantly connected. I'm running proxmox, which I understand is just extra software on top of standard debian.

Comment: @bilogic : proxmox ??? OMG well… that is not exactly what I would call *"extra software on top"* (since at least it provides its own kernel replacing the original from debian)… I was wondering about device id 1 missing in all your reports and no default pre-installed configuration file. Everything is clear now and well above my knowledge. (The need for and the impact of some pass-thru device to have your usb sound device  working being at least among the unknown-to-me). Sorry Old Pal ! I won't be of any help to you. (You probably should tell about *promox* in your question) Good luck anyway.

Comment: As a last try, you could try **id 0 for the usb and 2 for the hda**, (avoiding id 1 possibly reserved for some hidden virtual device).